# Association not working in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am a newbie in Spring but learned quite a lot over the last weeks. I have a Spring Boot project which works fine for simple resources, but once I do associations, some things don't work as expected.

My simplified application has the Resources Event and Invitation, where an event can have multiple invitations.

Now I have two problems:

1. When I do a call on the API for events, I get the events, but there are no invitations in the output. I see in my MySqlLogs, that there is a query querying for invitations and when I copy and past this query into my mysql client, I get a lot of results
2. There is no JOIN between event and invitations. There is one event query, and then one query for invitations for each event in the result. But I would expect a JOIN here in order to have just one query. I tried these annoatations

   @OneToMany(mappedBy="event", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
   @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)

but they didn't make any difference. Does anyone sees why there are no invitations in my API output and why there are single queries instead of a JOIN?

Thanks a lot for your help.

The example output I see is:

```
{
    content: [
      {
        id: 374223,
        start: "2016-12-12 17:30",
        end: "2016-12-12 20:00",
        name: "Hallentraining",
        slug: "hallentraining-501-2016-12-12",
        invitations: [
            {
                id: 0,
                message: null,
                invitationState: 1,
                memberId: null,
                version: 0
            }
        ],
        version: 0
       }
     ],
    last: true,
    totalPages: 1,
    totalElements: 1,
    first: true,
    sort: null,
    numberOfElements: 1,
    size: 20,
    number: 0
}
```

Event Class

```
@Entity
@Component
@Table(name="event")
public class Event implements MyEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String slug;

    @Column(name="start")
    @Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
    private DateTime start;

    @Column(name="end")
    @Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
    private DateTime end;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="event", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private Set<Invitation> invitations = new HashSet<>();

// getters and setters 
}
```

Invitation Class

```
@Entity
@Component
@Table(name="invitation")
public class Invitation implements MyEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;



    private String message;

    @Column(name="invitation_state")
    private Integer invitationState;

    @Column(name="member_id")
    private Integer memberId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="event_id", nullable=false)
    private Event event;

    // getters and setters 
}
```

EventRepository:

```
public interface  EventRepository extends JpaRepository<Event, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor {

}
```

EventController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/event" , produces="application/json")
public class EventController {

    @Autowired
    private EventRepository repo;

    @Autowired
    private EventService eventService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)

     public Iterable<Event> event(Pageable pageable,
                                 String start ,
                                 String end ,
                                 String name) {
        EventSpecification spec = new EventSpecification(start, end, name );

        return repo.findAll( spec, pageable );
    }
}
```

Extract of my build.gradle:

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '1.3.6.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '1.3.6.RELEASE'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.5.0'
compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.34'
compile group: 'joda-time', name: 'joda-time', version: '2.9.5'
compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-joda', version: '2.8.4'
compile group: 'org.jadira.usertype', name: 'usertype.core', version: '3.2.0.GA'
```

Comment: For your first problem, can you confirm the foreign data between `event` and `invitation` are correct? 
For example, executing query `select count(*) from invitation where event_id not in (select id from event)` in mysql client.

Comment: In general the foreign key data is correct. I opened the mysql logs and saw the executed queries. Once I executed it in my mysql client, it returned the expected result.
But for your query, there are still a lot of invitation that doesn't match with an event, because I just copied some random data in my test object. But for the events I tested with, there are invitations  available. Or is there any kind of problem when the query above doens't return "0"?

Comment: I test your code using HSQLDB and it works as expected. Are `invitation` and `event` created by Spring JPA? If they are created by yourself, could you check the column type of `invitation.event_id` and `evnet.id`?